# How to do the server side pagination using angular-ui bootstrap using skip parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have a number of items generated using ng-repeat, i have to add pagination.but everywhere i can see by getting the count value of items, i can add. but i am not able to get using skip. i.e if the skip value is 10, it will skip the first items and list the other items,i need to do like using the skip value using angular-ui bootstrap. 
 
  following code inside services

```
mainEvents: function() {
        var self = this;
        var skipNumber=2;
        return $http.get(UrlService.baseUrl + '/event/upcoming?count='+ skipNumber).then(function(response) {
            // var events = response.data;
            var events = response.data.events;
            var upEvents=[];

            var eventsLen = events.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < eventsLen; i++) {
                self.prepareForRendering(events[i]);
            }
            var totalItems = response.data.events.length;

            angular.copy(response.data.events, upEvents)
             console.log(upEvents);
            // angular.copy(response.data.tracks, $scope.tracks)
            return events;

        }, function(response) {
            return $q.reject(response.data.error)
        });
    },
$scope.pageChanged = function() {
    mainEvents();
  };
```

**markup**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="event in events">{{event.name}}</li>
</ul>

<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="skipNumber" ng-change="pageChanged()" items-per-page="1"></pagination>
```

Based on page number clicked,skipNumber to be incremented by 10, 20 etc.., How to do it.can anyone please help me

Comment: Can you please make it more understandable? You want to have set of 10 fresh data values from backend on each call and it has to be subsequent data.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite from the backend i am using skip. if i send request with `apiurl?skip=10` it will skip first 10 items, for the first page skip should be 0, for the second page it should be 10 goes on like this. i want to display only 10 items at a time

Comment: I think the `ng-model` would actually be the page number so remove it from the `pageChanged()` method and either on your client site or on server site you need to multiply the current page number by the number of items per page to get the skip number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/619ryubL/4/).

The `events` variable is an array, so you can use `slice` method with it:
`ng-repeat="event in events.slice( (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage, currentPage * itemsPerPage )"`.

You have set `itemsPerPage` as `1` here: `items-per-page="1"` and `currentPage` is `($scope.skipNumber / $scope.itemsPerPage) + 1` (the devision result here must be an integer).

The resulting html would look like:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="event in events.slice( (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage, currentPage * itemsPerPage)">{{event.name}}</li>
</ul>

<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
```

Comment: i have used like u mentioned. but if i change items-per-page also, it is showing only one item. in console i am getting 4 items

Comment: @Coder I don't think I understand you right. `items-per-page` is set to `1` in your snippet, so it does what you have specified, show `1` item on the page. Was it the problem?

Comment: i have changed `items-per-page' to 4, but it is not showing 4 items . instead it is showing one. 
and also when it is 1, pagecount is not incremented. it is showing `previous, 1 , next` but next and previous is disabled. can u tell me where i am doing wrong

Comment: if i remove events.slice in ng-repeat. it will show all the events, but not when i added it

Comment: @Coder I have made some changes, would you check them, is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: i think i have done some mistake here, items-per-page is not working correctly. if there are 5 pages also, it will be showing like `previous,1,next` rather than showing  `previous,1,2,3,next`. but i am not getting where i did mistake. and also next and previous also disabled when more pages. it is looking like static

Comment: @Coder could you set up your own plunkr?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. it is working somehow. but the calculation is not what i expected. i am passing the currentNumber value to the get request like this `apiUrl?skip=currentNumber` , initially i am setting the skip number as zero. (so as to get the first events without skipping anything). later it should increment according to items per page

Comment: And also the currentNumber is not incrementing based on page number clicks

Comment: i have used ng-click and pagechanged function and i am calling function inside pagechanged like this. 
`$scope.pageChanged = function() {
        $scope.mainEvents(); //factory function which returns the events
      };`

Comment: please help me on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112378/discussion-between-georgy-and-coder).